# Cannot start a script

Tags: linux, unix, shell-scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<man.txt)
echo "$value"

if [ "$value" == "true" ]; then
    echo "startedif_manthan"
      ps -ef|grep sym |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9;
      sleep 30;
    sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server;
fi
```

I have this script killing a process and restart the script in some time. It is killing the script normally but the restart script `sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server` is not running properly.

When I run the script manually also it is giving problems. I don't know whether it is a shell script or not. But when I tried to go manually to the script location and execute this command `./sym --port 8082 --server` the script running normally.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's the error message ?

Comment: It is not executing the script(sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server) after killing it just terminate from execution.

Comment: I got it,  bcoz the script itself is matching the pattern to kill it is killing itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

value=$(<man.txt)

echo "$value"

if [ "$value" == "true" ]; then

    echo "startedif_manthan"

      ps -ef|grep sym |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9;

      sleep 30;

    sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.3.1/bin/sym --port 8082

fi

save it as my.sh

This works fine with **symmetric-ds-3.3.1** .

Put echo "true">man.txt
```

Comment: Fine, except don't use kill -9 as anything other than a last resort.  Kill it normally, and then follow up with a -9 if it refuses to die.

Answer (score 1):

If your script is killing itself then there are a couple of options

- rename the script so that it nolonger matches you grep RE.
- change the grep RE so that it is unique to the program you want to kill.

Answer (score 0):

Change directory first

```
cd /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/
```

and then run

```
sh sym --port 8082 --server
```

It probably searches for some file in current directory.

Comment: Thanks man. I got it, bcoz the script itself is matching the pattern to kill it is killing itself.

Comment: one more question. I need to put this script in cron. I'm using sudo(i have to) in the script. Will it run without password in cron?

Comment: There is NOPASSWD option for sudo (http://zipizap.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/allow-user-to-use-sudo-without-password/).  Never tried it but it should work.